# To create index on a varchar column or not - Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have read a couple of articles about when to create an index on a column and all of those were related to Mysql, SQL Server or Oracle. I have a fair bit of idea now about whether I should create an index on my column or not, but I would like to have a learned opinion on it before I actually try it.

I have a MS Access database which has around 15 tables. All tables have a column called `[Locations]` and this column is used in almost all `WHERE` clauses and most of the `JOIN` conditions. This column has 5 distinct values as of now i.e 5 locations viz A, B, C, D, E.

So my question is though this column is part of most `WHERE` clause and `JOIN`, the limited variety in values (just 5) is making me to hesitate to create an index on it.

Please advice.

Comment: Sounds to me like locations should be a table with an Id as the primary key and that id used as a foreign key in all the other tables.

Comment: I second what @MattWilko says.  You can then certainly create an index on the foreign key column if it is going to be used as a filter in queries.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. In every table the locations are stored with their original values i.e A, B, C, D, E

Comment: Usually such low variability does not need index. But you have to test with your slower queries - sometimes such index may change query internal logic, especially on MS Access, and make query faster (or slower).

Comment: We have almost the same case. A Status field char(1) with 4 distinct values, available in all tables. The Status is included in every Where clause. I´m not aware of any index which included the Status field. We encounter no performance issues. And we are talking about millions of records in some tables.

Comment: @AlexB, is your database MS access? Also is it placed on a network drive and accessed by users from different locations across globe?

Comment: 1. No it´s SQL Server, should have mentioned that sorry. 2. YesAndNo. The database is hosted and mirrored on several dedicated servers. But it is accessed by 10k+ users from different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to bear in mind that an Access database is a "peer-to-peer" (as opposed to "client-server") database, so table scans can be particularly detrimental to performance, especially if the back-end database file is on a network share. Therefore it is always a good idea to ensure that there are indexes on all fields that participate in WHERE clauses or the ON conditions of JOINs.

Example: I have a sample table with one million rows and a field named [Category] that contains the value 'A' or 'B'. Without an index on the [Category] field the query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM [TestData] WHERE [Category] = 'B'
```

had to do a table scan and that generated about 48 MB of total network traffic. Simply adding an index on [Category] reduced the total network traffic to 0.27 MB for the exact same query.

Comment: In the faster (indexed) case, Access doesn't need read anything from `TestData` ... it can just use the index.  This is a brilliant example of an often-unrecognized benefit from indexing.

Comment: Makes Sense. Thank you!